# How abstract common classes?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Am developing webapplication with JSF and Hibernate, have Entity, Entity data access & JSF managed bean classes in following pattern and same repeats in all the classes. Since all the classes have the same pattern, I would like to make it as abstract class.

#### Entity Class

```
public class MyEntity {
-----
-----
}
```

#### Data Access class

```
public class MyEntityDAO extends AbstractDAO<MyEntity> {
MyEnitityDAO(){
-------
   }
}
```

#### JSF Managed bean

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private MyEntity current;
private MyEntityDAO dao;
private DataModel<MyEntity> items = null;

public MyBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyEntity getCurrent() {
    return current;
}

public void setCurrent(MyEntity current) {
    this.current = current;
}

public MyEntityDAO getDao() {
    if (dao == null) {
        dao = new MyEntityDAO();
    }
    return dao;
}

public DataModel<MyEntity> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public List<MyEntity> getMyEntityList() {
    return getDao().findAll();
}
public MyEntity getMyEntity(int id) {
    return getDao().findById(id);
}
    private void reSetDataModel() {
    items = null;
}
private void reSetCurrent() {
    setCurrent(null);
}

public void prepareCreate() {
    current = new MyEntity();
}

public void create() {
    // Save the entity
}
public void edit() {
    // Update the entity
}
public void delete() {
    // Remove the entity
}
}
```

How to make the abstract class out of above pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Type the word `abstract` between `public` and `class`

Comment: Here instance variables MyEntity and MyEntityDAO are varies for each concrete class.